# What is the most popular C++ gui framework in windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, user-interface

Nowadays there are many windows applications. Several years ago, MFC may be the most popular gui framework to create windows applications. But I think MFC is too old and doesn't have a good OO design. So here I want to know is there any modern, well designed and widely used C++ gui framework in windows?

Comment: MFC/ATL or whatever it's called these days. It has evolved you know.

Comment: I vote for Qt. It's a great and popular framework for GUIs in C++.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: MFC and ATL are two well different things. there is no MFC/ATL framework. (at most there are some common classes, but no more than that!)

Comment: You're asking a very subjective/time based question, it's really not a good fit for this site as per the [FAQ]

Comment: If you guys are going to censor this question, can you at least provide a link to somewhere that has the answer? Notice that the question doesn't ask "what GUI API should I use?" or "what is the best?". It asks "what is the most popular?", which is not subjective in the slightest. The question is: How would we know what is the most popular? Is there such data available? Can you look at a program and tell what API was used? Sometimes you can, right? Would it require surveying developers? I don't understand the point of closing this question. I would be very interested in the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My company use Qt framework.
Adobe Photoshop (AFAIK) and other popular Windows programs are using it.
Qt is modern, well documented and tested. Just try it and enjoy :)

Answer (score 4):

If you need a free portable GUI framework you can use wxWidgets. QT is also a choice, but AFAIK it's not completely free.

So the answer depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thank your for downvoting a valid answer without any reasons given. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115045/good-c-gui-library-for-windows) which seems similar to yours.

It states QT as a decent free GUI solution.

Comment: QT is not completely free.